# Can Pyudev detect bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth, device, pyudev

I am writing an application which monitors some devices connected to the computer. I loop over all the devices like this :

```
from pyudev import Context, Monitor, MonitorObserver
context = Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
for device in context.list_devices():
  print_device(device)
```

USB devices are detected, along with most of built-in boards (ethernet, ...), but no clue of devices connected in Bluetooth (paired and connected in rfcomm).
Am I missing something, or is Pyudev simply not capable of discovering such devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

udev (and thus pydev) is only meant to tell you about devices on the local system. It can't tell you about remote devices.